# Overfull \vbox (1116.51286pt too high)

Tags: graph, latex

I am trying to plot two graphs in one document using latex
first is of sinx and cosx
the otherare its inverse

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\title{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\section{Sine and Cosine}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[clip=false,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=2.5*pi,
        ymin=-1.5,
        ymax=1.5,
        axis lines=middle,
        xtick={0,pi/2,3*pi/2,2*pi},
        xticklabels={$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$2\pi$},
        xticklabel style={anchor=south west},
        xmajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
        ]
        \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,red,samples=100]{sin(deg(x))}
        node[right,pos=0.9]{$f(x)=sin(x)$};
        \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,blue,samples=100]{cos(deg(x))}
        node[right,pos=0.9]{$g(x)=cos(x)$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{Inverse Sine and Cosine}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[clip=false,
        ymin=-1.5*pi,
        ymax=1.5*pi,
        xmin=-1.5,
        xmax=1.5,
        axis lines=middle,
        ytick={-pi/2,0,pi/2},
        yticklabels={-$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$},
        yticklabel style={anchor=north west},
        xmajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
        ]
        \addplot[domain=-1:1,red,samples=100]{asin(x/180*pi)}
        node[right,pos=0.9]{$f(x)=sin^{-1}(x)$};
        \addplot[domain=-1:1,blue,samples=100]{acos(x/180*pi)}
        node[right,pos=0.9]{$g(x)=cos^{-1}(x)$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

here is the code
first i tried with only one section and it worked just fine but when i added another section
it gave the error:
Overfull \vbox (1116.51286pt too high)

I am new to latex so please ignore any rookie mistakes
I have attached the output image it is ploting both graph on different pages is there anyway to plot them on the same page.
[image: Second graph]
[image: First graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with latex, just a math problem: Don't convert the argument of acos to rad, it is the result of the expression which you want to convert.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\title{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\section{Sine and Cosine}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[clip=false,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=2.5*pi,
        ymin=-1.5,
        ymax=1.5,
        axis lines=middle,
        xtick={0,pi/2,3*pi/2,2*pi},
        xticklabels={$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$2\pi$},
        xticklabel style={anchor=south west},
        xmajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
        ]
        \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,red,samples=100]{sin(deg(x))}
        node[right,pos=0.9]{$f(x)=sin(x)$};
        \addplot[domain=0:2*pi,blue,samples=100]{cos(deg(x))}
        node[right,pos=0.9]{$g(x)=cos(x)$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\section{Inverse Sine and Cosine}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[clip=false,
%        ymin=-1.5*pi,
%        ymax=1.5*pi,
        xmin=-1.5,
        xmax=1.5,
        axis lines=middle,
        ytick={-pi/2,0,pi/2},
        yticklabels={-$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$},
        yticklabel style={anchor=north west},
        xmajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
        ]
        \addplot[domain=-1:1,red,samples=100]{rad(asin(x))}
        node[right,pos=0.9]{$f(x)=sin^{-1}(x)$};
        \addplot[domain=-1:1,blue,samples=100]{rad(acos(x))}
        node[right,pos=0.9]{$g(x)=cos^{-1}(x)$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]